# How to create a selection of bound items in a context menu in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I'm currently working on a frontend for an emulator in WPF, and am having trouble with this seemingly basic function.

I am trying to create a simple selection of items from within a context menu (in this case of an image). A picture explains it a little better:

[image]

I want only one at a time to be selectable/checkable, this data then sets a value in my model which is eventually written to an external file. In a prototype I had that bound to a combobox with two-way binding but that doesn't really make sense with this design.

I tried a couple of different approaches, but did not manage to figure out a proper solution (specifically how to control the isChecked of the non clicked items).

My context menu (xaml) looks like this:

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Header="PCSX2 Version" ItemsSource="{Binding Versions}">
        <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="StaysOpenOnClick" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="BindingGroup" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}}}" />
                <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="SetVersion" />
            </Style>
        </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="Config" ItemsSource="{Binding Configs}" />
    <MenuItem Header="Create Config" BindingGroup="{Binding}" Click="ShowConfigWizard"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

And my model is shown below, not much works in the code behind (`SetVersion` function) yet. As you can see below, I tried a solution involving binding a Tuple but couldn't get that to work (the `ischecked` value never updated, despite the bound condition being no longer true).

I also tried a radio button based solution (again couldn't get it to work), and just setting checked to false for all items from code behind (was unable to select the sibling menu items from the binding).

```
public class GameModel : ICloneable
{
    public string Game { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Versions { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Tuple<string, bool>> VersionsAndStates => Versions.Select(version => new Tuple<string, bool>(version, Version == version));
    public string Version { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Configs { get; set; }
    public string Config { get; set; }
    public string CoverPath { get; set; }

    object ICloneable.Clone() => Clone();
    public GameModel Clone() => (GameModel) MemberwiseClone();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As is typical I just posted asking about a solution then I figured it out I was so close, just a slight oversight on my part about how the ViewModel works. I'll put my solution below in case anyone else has a similar problem. The main change was in my model.

```
public class GameModel : ICloneable, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Game { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Versions { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Tuple<string, bool>> VersionsAndStates => Versions.Select(version => new Tuple<string, bool>(version, Version == version));
    private string version;
    public string Version 
    {
        get => version;
        set
        {
            version = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Version)));
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(VersionsAndStates)));
        }
    }
    public IEnumerable<string> Configs { get; set; }
    public string Config { get; set; }
    public string CoverPath { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    object ICloneable.Clone() => Clone();
    public GameModel Clone() => (GameModel) MemberwiseClone();
}
```

and my xaml

```
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="PCSX2 Version" ItemsSource="{Binding VersionsAndStates}">
            <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Item1}" />
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Item2, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    <Setter Property="StaysOpenOnClick" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Property="BindingGroup" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}}}" />
                    <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="SetVersion" />
                </Style>
            </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Config" ItemsSource="{Binding Configs}" />
        <MenuItem Header="Create Config" BindingGroup="{Binding}" Click="ShowConfigWizard"/>
    </ContextMenu>
```

And then setting Version on the model to the selected header in my code behind